# Dynamic Websocket objects with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, websocket

I want to open a varying number of web sockets, each one connecting to a different server.
I'm storing the objects in an array, and assign them all to the same event handlers.

```
for (var i = 0; i < servers.length; i++) {
    var wsUri = constructWebSocketURI(servers[i], port);
    var currentWebSocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);

    currentWebSocket.onopen = function (evt) { onOpen(evt) };
    currentWebSocket.onclose = function (evt) { onClose(evt) };
    currentWebSocket.onmessage = function (evt) { onMessage(evt) };
    currentWebSocket.onerror = function (evt) { onError(evt) };

    WebSocketsArr.push(ws);
}
```

But how can I differentiate between them inside the event handlers (`onMessage`, `onError` etc)?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your handler functions to receive an extra parameter for the server name (or whatever other value) and then just pass a different parameter to you handlers when registering the websockets. You just have to take care of creating the proper closure around the value you want to use as a discriminator, something like:

```
var createFunc = function (handlerToCall, discriminator) {
    return function(evt) {
        handlerToCall(evt, discriminator);
    };
}

for (var i = 0; i < servers.length; i++) {
    var wsUri = constructWebSocketURI(servers[i], port);
    var currentWebSocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
    var currentServerName = "server_" + i; // or whatever

    currentWebSocket.onopen = createFunc(onOpen, currentServerName);
    currentWebSocket.onclose = createFunc(onClose, currentServerName);
    currentWebSocket.onmessage = createFunc(onMessage, currentServerName);
    currentWebSocket.onerror = createFunc(onError, currentServerName); 

    WebSocketsArr.push(currentWebSocket);
}
```